# Can Inner join be used effeciently with RIGHT or LEFT Join together in single mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I am working on php-mysql script and having two tables namely messages and members. The data in these tables is given below for example:

messages table:

```
_________________________________________________________________
|m_id| from_id | to_id | msg_subject | msg_body     | sent_time  |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    142  |  335  |    hello    |  how are you | 2017-25-10 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |    225  |  443  |    hi       |  whats up..  | 2017-26-10 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  |    332  |  110  |    urgent   |  call me now | 2017-27-10 |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and members table:

```
______________________________________________________________
| id   | username | f_name  |  l_name   |   city    | gender  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 110  |    joe   |  Joe    |    Tom    |  Rome     |    M    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 142  |    alb_p |  Albert |    Paul   |  Milan    |    M    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 225  |    ruby  |  Ruby   |    Hinge  |  Paris    |    F    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 332  |    ram   |  Ram    |    Sharma |  Delhi    |    M    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 335  |   kris   |  Kity   |    Krin   |  Milan    |    F    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 443  |    reema |  Reema  |    Pink   |  Dubai    |    F    |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want these tables are joined in mysql query in such a way (or use two select in mysql) so that i should get the username, f_name, l_name, city and gender data of for every from_id and to_id. And also I should also get msg_subject,msg_body and sent_time. I am getting this with use of another mysql query in while loop, which I dont want to use because of performance issue for more than 500 rows. Finally I want display the following type of output using html in the web browser:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
|m_id|  Message       |   Message      | Message  |   Message    | Msg Sent |
|    | From Member    |   To Member    | Subject  |   Details    |  On Date |    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    |ID: 142         | ID: 335        |          |              |          |
|    |UserName: alb_p | UserName: kris |          |              |          |
|    |1st Name:Albert | 1st Name: Kity |          |              |          |
| 1  |Last Name: Paul | Last Name: Krin|  hello   | how are you  |2017-25-10|
|    |City: Milan     | City: Milan    |          |              |          |
|    |Gender: Male    | Gender: Female |          |              |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    |ID: 225         | ID: 443        |          |              |          |
|    |UserName: ruby  | UserName:reema |          |              |          |
|    |1st Name:Ruby   | 1st Name:Reema |          |              |          |
| 2  |Last Name:Hinge | Last Name:Pink |  hi      | Whats up..   |2017-26-10|
|    |City: Paris     | City: Dubai    |          |              |          |
|    |Gender: Female  | Gender: Female |          |              |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on... for m_id row no. 3 also..

I am getting this html table style output as shown above using another mysql query in while loop but i want to achieve this in a single mysql query using double select or two joins. Please suggest me the way and give me that mysql query details.... thanks in advance.. (also to disclose I am just a starter in php-mysql programming..)

Comment: There ain’t much of this so-called script here

Comment: yes. all join types can be used efficiently in a sql query, if a whole bunch of conditions exist. but to be fair there is an unwritten rule that one doesn't need to (and does not)  use a "right join" as a query can be restructured to use left joins instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of using 2 left joins for "from member" and "to member"

```
select
       m.*, from_men.username, to_mem.username
from messages m
left join members as from_mem on m.from_id = from_mem.id
left join members as to_mem   on m.to_id = to_mem.id
```

Comment: Thanks Used_By_Already i am getting you and understood query, but please also tell me how to move further to get these values in array and use while loop for displaying these value finally to show in browser. Please elaborate code more to display the wanted result. thanks a ton!

Comment: I cannot help with php. Suggest you find a tutorial.

Comment: Ok Thanks Used_By_Already, I have done it and wrote the rest of the code myself. Thanks for the help on Left Join concept. My work is done.

Comment: Accepted... Clicked on Right Tick